# Place const variable to specific address in flash of LPC4074 with LPCXpresso gcc without further usage of variable

Tags: variables, gcc, constants, lpc, lpcxpresso

I want to place a const variable to a specific flash address containing a bootloader version on my LPC4074 in LPCXpresso 8.2.2.
Since gcc compiler doesn't support "@" sign and everything I read up to now is an "__attribute__ ((section.." I did it this way:

```c
__attribute__ ((section(".rodata.$MFlashData"))) const uint8_t IOLM_BLVersion[] = {C_VERSION_MAJOR,C_VERSION_MINOR,C_VERSION_BUILD};
```

This is the memory setting:
[Picture of memory settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cKK0.png)

But although I disabled compiler optimization by "-O0" it seems that gcc eliminates this variable. I don't find it in map file as well as in memory window at the adress in debugger.
Although if I add somewhere a dummy read in an if condition or assign it to another variable it's not there as expected.

The only solution I found so far is a dummy function call with an internal crc calculation function:

```c
(void)iol_fw_ddl_crc_calc((uint8_t*)IOLM_BLVersion, 3);
```

Since it passes the pointer now it seems to be "used".

Is there any other more elegant way to place some fixed values on specific flash addresses?
E.g. a pragma switch or more options with the attribute-directive?